# Как объединить 2 запроса?

Tags: php

Вывожу из таблицы данные `while...` и хочу, например, через каждые 10 записей из таблицы 1 вставлять по одной записи из второй таблицы.

**UPD:** вывожу данные из таблицы 1.

```
$sql = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id,title FROM table1 ORDER BY id DESC');
$sql->execute();
while ($news = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
        echo '<h2>'.$news->title.'</h2>';
    }
```

Существует вторая таблица `table2`, где данные будут выводится таким же способом. Сделать нужно так, чтобы когда выводятся данные из `table1`, через каждые 10 записей выводилась одна запись из `table2` туда же, где выводятся основные данные из `table1`.

К примеру:

```
1 //table1
2 //table1
3 //table1
4 //table1
5 //table1
6 //table1
7 //table1
8 //table1
9 //table1
10 //table1
как дела? //table2
11 //table1
12 //table1
```

Comment: Способ "в лоб" заводите себе перед началом цикла переменную `$sql1=$pdo->prepare("select a from table2"); $sql1->execute();` в цикле считаете сколько уже вывели записей и на каждую 10ю (остаток от деления номера цикла на 10 равен 0) делаете sql1->fetch и печатаете. Вариант 2 - говорите какая у вас СУБД, мне интересно это одним запросом к БД сделать :) Хотя первый способ наверное проще ... :)

Comment: @Mike, `MySQL (MyISAM)`

Comment: "В лоб" наверное проще :) ибо запросик веселый вышел: `select * from (
select title,@a:=@a+1 num,1 tab
  from table1,(select @a:=0) B
 order by X desc
) A
union
select B.* from (
 select X as title,@b:=@b+10 num,2 tab
   from table2,(select @b:=0) B
  order by v
) B,(select count(1) maxB from table1) C
where B.num<=C.maxB
order by num,tab
`

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, наверное попробую сделать по первому варианту)

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавить счетчик в начале цикла

```
$j++;
if ($j%10 == 0) {
 //здесь вставляем из 2й таблицы
}
```